# Selenium explicit wait accepts EC.visibility_of_element_located xpath element incorrectly

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am currently running selenium pytest automation and am running into an issue with explicit wait. I have a WebDriverWait function like such:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((
    By.XPATH, '//div[@class="ant-card ant-card-bordered" and //*[contains(text(), "Access Points")]]')))
```

where this specific xpath element does not exist on the page.

[Image of page where xpath element does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msRCQ.png)

As such I expect a failed test case. The bizzare thing is that it does work as expected using a docker image and successfully produces a timeout exception, but when run on local web browser it passes through the explicit wait without any timeout exception. I believe there is something weird with the xpath element, because when I edit the text() attribute to a string that does not exist on the page it properly fails. Note that when searching for xpath element with chrome inspect tools the element is not found as seen in the image above

Comment: What answer do you expect? Wait is correct. HTML code is absent, so it's not possible to verify the locator.

Comment: Exactly, so I would expect since HTML is absent, that the WebDriverWait raises a Timeout Exception, but it does not.

Comment: So, look for a bug in your code

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I am having troubles reproducing on any other page then this page itself. Here is the scenario. This xpath element used to be a valid xpath element but has since been changed to something else. Now that it has changed I would expect the WebdriverWait to produce a timeout exception. I have reduced the Xpath element to '//div[@class="ant-card ant-card-bordered"]' and it still does not raise timeout exception even though this element does not exist on the page. I am not familiar with front end, but is it possible this is somehow saved from an older deployment behind the scenes? Or cached?

Comment: Additionally changing the class attribute even slightly from the provided one, produces the timeout exception, which makes me think the element is still there in someway or another but not sure how.

Comment: If the waiter doesn‘t raise a timeout, what element does it return then? Did you inspect it?

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the attached image: the selected div does not contain the text "Access Points". Let's remove it from the XPath or try to find another div that actually contains such text.